# How have default value in filter with session [Sonata Admin]

Tags: php, session, symfony, sonata-admin

I would like have a dynamic value of session for the default value of filterParameters

This code working :

```
/**
 * Default Datagrid values
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $datagridValues = array(
    'applications' => array('value' => 'Sport TV'),
    '_sort_order' => 'ASC'
);

// Fields to be shown on filter forms
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('title')
        ->add('applications', null, array('label' => 'Chaîne'), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true));
}
```

But when I add the session, he don't want that I use this outside the
function :

```
public function getApplicationsSession()
{
    $session = new Session();
    return $session->get('applications');
}

/**
 * Default Datagrid values
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $datagridValues = array(
    'applications' => array('value' => $this->getApplicationsSession()),
    '_sort_order' => 'ASC'
);
```

I have this errors :

`Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)`

Thanks to helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code it's the error cause:

```
protected $datagridValues = array(
    'applications' => array('value' => $this->getApplicationsSession()),
                                         ^---- syntax error !
    '_sort_order' => 'ASC'
);
```

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs... http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

To solve that, you should to override the `getFilterParameters()` method:

```
public function getFilterParameters()
{
    $this->datagridValues['applications']['value'] = $this->getApplicationsSession();

    return parent::getFilterParameters();
}
```